# Is it possible to render a partial using absolute path?

Tags: octobercms

I'm developing an OctoberCMS plugin that has a component that renders a different partial depending on the data in the model supplied to the component. The problem I'm having is that I only seem to be able to render a partial if it belongs to a component or the theme partial folder. I'd like to be able to register new model types from other plugins and have their views in the same plugin folder, eg:

- models

  - mymodel

    - view.htm
  - MyModel.php

I basically want the `onRender` of the main component to make the decision of which partial to render, eg:

```
public function onRender()
{
    // Some code here to determine which partial to render

    return $this->renderPartial($pathToPartial);
}
```

Comment: It depends can you share `more details` which data you `want to make available in partial` .. if its data `just you pass as params` then its `super easy`.. other wise if you need `partial which have all global data like page controller and all component alias ` Up ON THAT  `you pass custom params` as well  etc then i need to work little more hard :)

Comment: Currently I only have the need to pass the model to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then good, we can use 2 engines 1. `default PHP` and another one is 2. `twig`

### For PHP Engine

> First we need to add helper `ViewMaker trait` in to component

```
class CompoOne extends ComponentBase
{    
    use \System\Traits\ViewMaker; // <- we need to add partial/view related method makeView
```

> Now we will add two methods `render method` and `custom Render method`

As I don't want to override default behavior I will add `extension` with `custom render`.

```
public function customRender() {

    // this will be our logic 
    $partialPath = $this->vars['parialPath'] ?? 'default';
    return $this->makeView($partialPath);
}

public function onRender()
{
    // this will decide which partial we need to render
    $this->vars['parialPath'] = '$/hardiksatasiya/demotest/main';

    // $ <- start from plugin dir
    // $this->vars['parialPath'] = '~/main'; 
    // ~ <- start from root dir

    // data you want to pass to your partial 
    $this->vars['model'] = 'your model';

}
```

> This will let component render its **default partial** `default.htm`. Now it's code

```
<h1>Component Parital</h1>
<div class="dynamic-partial">
    {{__SELF__.customRender()|raw }}
<div>
```

> And our custom partial `$/hardiksatasiya/demotest/main` , it will be like `my_project_root_path/plugins + /hardiksatasiya/demotest/main` here `main` will be `main.htm automatically` so `main.htm` code

```
<div class="my-partial">
    Its ok to have partial <?= $model ?>.
</div>
```

**Final out-put for this component will be**

```
<h1>Component Parital</h1>
<div class="dynamic-partial">
    <div class="my-partial">
        Its ok to have partial your model.
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Execution Flow**

First `onRender` will be called here we set `vars` which will contain `partial path` **[you can put it from component config or from else ]**

It will call `default.htm` this will call our custom `customRender` method

Now we `finally` call our `dynamic partial`, inside it all variables will be available which we defined inside `$this->vars[]` automatically. **[ in demo I have added $this->vars['model'] like this ]**

### For Twig Engine

Just follow PHP engine steps with this instructions

> We don't need to add helper `ViewMaker trait` in to component (so skip that step)
>
> We change our `custom Render method` to use twig engine

```
public function customRender() {

    // twig engine
    $partialPath = $partialPath = $this->vars['parialPath'] ?? 'default';
    $partialPath = $partialPath . '.htm';

    if (\File::isPathSymbol($partialPath)) {
        $partialPath = \File::symbolizePath($partialPath);
    }

    $template = $this->controller->getTwig()->loadTemplate($partialPath);
    $partialContent = $template->render($this->vars);

    return $partialContent;
}
```

> Our custom partial file code will be

```
<div class="my-partial">
    Its ok to have partial {{ model }}
</div>
```

out-put will be same as above

> We can use `twig` tags here and `all the variables` which will be assigned to `$this->vars` will be `available inside the partial`

If you have any doubt please comment

Comment: Thanks. That's got me somewhere, but it uses the PHP template not the Twig template. Is there anyway to use Twig?

Comment: ok, I need to work little bit for that  but sure it can do that np, i will work on that and update answer

Comment: answer updated with `twig engine` please check it and let us know